# Remap Bluetooth Headset's media key [Android 9]

Tags: bluetooth, 9.0-pie, headphones, bluetooth-audio, media-button

Setup:

- OnePlus 5t, Android 9.0, not rooted
- Bluetooth 5.0 headset with one media button

A single tab on the media button starts the Google Voice Control / Assistant, there is no way to change a tab on the button to play/pause for example -  on the headset's side.

The only software solution to disable Google Voice popping up always when I press the button was to disable the Google-App completely. But this stops the media-button from working completely.

After hours of trying, searching nothing worked for me.

My goal is to archive that a tab leads to play/pause music.

Comment: If the headset manufacturer offers an app for configuring the headset you should check it out if it offers a way to reconfigure the button.

Comment: @Robert unfortunately this is not the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue by using a app called `AutoVoice` in combination with `Tasker`.

In Android Settings, `Apps, Default Apps, Assist & Voice Input` I selected AutoVoice.

In Tasker I created a Profile which is a `Event` triggered by `Plugins > AutoVoice > AutoVoice BT Pressed` and the connected Task contains only `Media Control`, `Switch Pause`, `Simulate Media Key` is activated and I selected a music app as `App`, in my case Spotify.

This works just fine.

Let me know if you have the same problem and have issues with my solution.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was to use MacroDroid:

1. Add Trigger - User Input - Volume Button Pressed - (Select the method) - (Select "Volume Up" or "Volume Down") - Retain Previous Volume
2. Add Action - Media - Control Media - (Select Media Control Type) - (Select "Next" or "Previous")
3. Add Constraint - Connectivity - Bluetooth State - Device Connected - (Select Device Connected)

On top of that, you can add a macro to turn off Bluetooth when you turn off your Bluetooth headphones

Works with a locked screen *without root*, but for some reason, only the next track works properly. Physical volume up and down (on phone) works just fine but it's enough for me. If you want to change the volume, just pause the music and the volume buttons will work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

I am an idiot. Just discovered if you double tap the left earbud it rewinds and right earbud fast forwards. These are Axloie $35 earbuds. Surprised. Haven't seen mention to this in the documentation.