# Remap Bluetooth headset buttons on Android

Tags: bluetooth, android-10, headphones, media-button

I have my Bluetooth headset and it has 3 buttons:

- BACK/Volume-
- NEXT/Volume+
- PLAY/STOP

I need to map one button (any of these) to take action after pressing (e.g. turn on the flashlight, or directly make a call to a specific person).

I found [Remap Bluetooth Headset's media key [Android 9]](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/218857/remap-bluetooth-headsets-media-key-android-9), so I installed AutoVoice and Tasker, but I am not able to call action after the button on the headset is pressed (of course, I am pretty newbie with AutoVoice and Tasker, so maybe my fault).

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

For this task, you could use ["Button Mapper"](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=flar2.homebutton) current version 3.09. You can not only remap the buttons to any action you want (even macros you define) but also add extra functions by defining actions for double or triple clicks.